# FeignClient: if the response of an API has two different format, how to elegantly deal with such a case?

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud-feign, feign

In my project there is a Feignclient as below:

```
@FeignClient(name = "myFeignClient", url = "${remote-url}", configuration = {MyApiClient.Config.class})
public interface ApiClient {

    @PostMapping(value = "/product", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
    ProductDTO getProduct(@RequestBody ProductReqParam req);

    ... // other @GetMapping or @PostMapping method is ignored here

    class Config {
        @Bean
        ErrorDecoder errorDecoder() {
            return new FeignErrorDecoder();
        }

        static class FeignErrorDecoder implements ErrorDecoder {
            @Override
            public Exception decode(String methodKey, Response response) {
                if (response.body() != null) {
                    return new MyFeignException(response.status(), response.body().toString());
                } else {
                    return new MyFeignException(response.status());
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

according to api document of our third-party provider, ProductDTO is as below

```
public class ProductDTO {

    @JsonProperty("Result")
    private ProductDTO.Result result;

    @Data
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public static class Result {
        @JsonProperty("STATUS")
        private String status;
        @JsonProperty("TOTALRECORD")
        private Integer recordCount;
        @JsonProperty("DATA")
        private List<Product> productList;
    }

    @Data
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public static class Product {
        @JsonProperty("ID")
        private Integer id;
        @JsonProperty("NAME")
        private String name;
        @JsonProperty("PRICE")
        private String price;
    }  
}
```

but after the project starts running on production environment, we find that if there is only one product record, the returned JSON corresponding to "DATA" key is a JSON instead of JSON Array，so the ProductDTO would be with field like this:

```
 @JsonProperty("DATA")
 private Product product;
```

Yes, the third-party api developer has done a very bad job in constructing their response to us, they should put the single object into a list and then return to us, but they don't, so we have to deal with the two different responses by ourselves.

I'm at a loss how to deal with such a case. My initial plan is to inject a customized feignDecoder bean, in decode method specifically deal with "/product" api. But it will disturbe other methods, also I've already have a ErrorDecoder bean, which may incur potential issues?

Comment: Why there are 2 `@JsonProperty("DATA")` annotations? Where is the second one from?

Comment: @Boris there are two different json responses

Comment: @Boris they are not in the same ProductDTO class, say, I can define two ProductDTO classes, ProductDTO1 and ProductDTO2, each with different @JsonProperty("DATA")

Comment: I see, and what happens if you have `@JsonProperty("DATA") private List<Product> productList;` in the ProductDTO2?

Comment: @Boris I'm asking how to deal with different responses, one with a list of objects while the other with a object

Comment: If I understand correctly, you should be able to marshall any JSON to `List<Product> productList`. Only in case the JSON contains a single `Product` it should be converted to a list of a single object. If you keep only `ProductDTO1` can it handle such scenario, can you try?

Comment: @Boris the issue is how to convert a single object in the response to a list of object. If I rewrite the decoder, how can I avoid affecting other APIs without such an issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207847/discussion-between-boris-and-lily).

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late but I believe what you're looking for is this:

```
@JsonFormat(with = ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY)
@JsonProperty("DATA")
private List<Product> products;
```

Based on the documentation [here](https://www.javadoc.io/static/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/2.9.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonFormat.Feature.html#ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY), this will allow deserialization of JSON non-array values into single-element Java arrays and Collections. So using this annotation, if the response of the API is a list, then it will be mapped to `List<Product>`. If the response of the API is a single Product object, then it will still be mapped to `List<Product>` with a single element.